# where is this dotted border coming from?

Tags: html, css

i have modified a wordpress theme very drastically to create the first version of my new site. I am trying to get rid of this 1px dotted border, but cannot for the life of me find which element it is on. arg!

the site is http://dev.timelesscreations.us and the dotted border i am talking about is underneath the side bar and above to footer on the right side.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
its in style.css line 62

#content
{
background: url("images/bk_content.png") repeat-y scroll 100% 0 transparent;
}

just REMOVE that property 
background: url("images/bk_content.png") repeat-y scroll 100% 0 transparent
from  #container  css

cheers
```

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by this CSS rule in your stylesheet:

```
#footer {
    ....
    border-top: 1px dotted #000;
    ....
}
```

Element:

```
<div id="footer"> .... </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox Firebug add-on or Chrome Developer Tools (F12) to find it.

Answer (score 1):

in style.css at line 144 you have dotted border setted on #footer. Remove that .